# how to open new tab on form onSubmit="return process();"

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://google.com/?hl=en&q=" + document.getElementById("query").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>

<form onSubmit="return process();" target="_blank">
query: <input type="text" name="query" id="query">
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

How to process this on new tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

you can write -

```
function process() {
    var url="http://google.com/?hl=en&q=" + document.getElementById("query").value;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place window.open(url,"_blank") insted of location.href=url;

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://google.com/?hl=en&q=" + document.getElementById("query").value;
window.open(url,"_blank");
return false;
}
```